# is there any way to fix dataset downloaded from the internett?

Tags: excel, datatables, dataset

[car sales data sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Z0H.png)The data i downloaded from the web is all over the place and not on their tables in Excel.I have tried to fix that data one each row but its 2464 rows with data and it is all mixed up. Is there a way in excel to fix that issue?

Comment: I am not very good with english especially in technical terms. I have a set of datasets in a excel format which if i'm correct are corrupted( the data is all mixed) and are not on their intended rows as it should be. i have googled this matter and even looked for answers in youtube, but no help there.

Comment: I think i put the link in the comment.

Comment: You can use Text to Columns.

Comment: Looks to be in CSV (comma-separated values) format. Perhaps when you save it, save it as `whatever.csv`. Excell should be able to open CSV files with no issues.